# Obtain the records where the primary key is in a List<guid> of keys in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq-to-sql

What is the best way to express a LINQ query where the query result only contains keys (of type guid) that are contained in a c# List?

In TSQL it would be something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE Keys IN (<guid1>,<guid2>,<guid3>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from row in db.MyView
where yourList.Contains(row.ID)
select row
```

Assuming yourList is a `List<Guid>` (certain collections cause an exception saying that "there is no supported translation to SQL", try it and if you get that error, make sure you have a List)

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something else wrong as I tried this and it comes back empty.  Let me look at the code again.

Comment: @RThomas is VW.Key nullable by any chance? I remember some problems. Attach the Debugger and make sure that VW.Key is actually in the listKeys :)

Comment: SHEEESH... visual studio and the 64 bit debugger frustrate me sometimes.  The problem was a couple lines above, it wasn't ever getting to this line.  SO yep, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Contains`.

```
List<Guid> keys = ...

var query = context.MyView.Where(v => keys.Contains(v.KeyColumn));
```

Comment: What is your experience with the performance of this approach vs the way that @Michael Stum provided above.  Does it compile to the same TSQL?  I suppose I could always run profiler and find out.

Comment: @RThomas: The approaches are the same. Michael's approach just uses the query syntax, whereas mine uses the extension method syntax. His query is turned into mine by the compiler.